# Openlayers - Add control: zoom/pan to current location

Tags: javascript, location, openlayers

I'm trying to add an ol.control button to the map that zooms/pans to my current location. I've extracted my location coordinates with:

```
var geolocation = new ol.Geolocation({
        projection: map.getView().getProjection(),
        tracking: true
    });
geolocation.getPosition(); //this shows the coordinates (e.g.[591374.2306195896, 6746799.171545821])
```

Now I want to use these as input for a "zoom to" ol.control button. As one would use ol.control.ZoomToExtent, which creates a control button. e.g.:

```
map.addControl(zoomToExtentControl);

zoomToExtentControl = new ol.control.ZoomToExtent({
  extent: [-1013450.0281739295, 3594671.9021477713, 6578887.117336057, 10110775.689402476],
  className: 'custom-zoom-extent',
  label: ''
});
```

Please help me out :-)

Comment: Have you seen this example in the documentation: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/animation.html

Answer (score 1):

The extent array used for the ZoomToExtent can be dynamically updated with the accuracy extent from the geolocation

```
var geolocation = new ol.Geolocation({
        projection: map.getView().getProjection(),
        tracking: true
    });

var extent = ol.extent.createEmpty();

geolocation.on('change:accuracyGeometry', function() {
    geolocation.getAccuracyGeometry().getExtent(extent);
});

zoomToExtentControl = new ol.control.ZoomToExtent({
  extent: extent,
  className: 'custom-zoom-extent',
  label: ''
});
```